# Unable to access member of anonymous structure inside union

Tags: union

I am using a union and an anonymous structure inside it. I want to know how I can access the structure member inside it. Like if i want to access G variable of structure using union variable then how can i do that. Please help :)

```
typedef union
{
 uint8_t All;                
 struct
 {
    uint8_t G:1;            
    uint8_t O_B:1;         
    uint8_t Unused:1;       
    uint8_t W1:1;          
    uint8_t W2:1;          
    uint8_t Y1:1;          
    uint8_t Y2:1;           
    uint8_t IAQ:1;          
 };
} _UNION_VARIABLE;
```

I am getting compilation error for accessing structure member like below :

```
_UNION_VARIABLE sg_RefreshVar; 

sg_RefreshVar.G = false;
```

Error : 
`#137 union "<unnamed>" has no field "G"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give it a name

```
typedef union
{
 uint8_t All;                
 struct
 {
    uint8_t G:1;            
    uint8_t O_B:1;         
    uint8_t Unused:1;       
    uint8_t W1:1;          
    uint8_t W2:1;          
    uint8_t Y1:1;          
    uint8_t Y2:1;           
    uint8_t IAQ:1;          
 } bit_field;
} _UNION_VARIABLE;
```

and then you can go

```
_UNION_VARIABLE.bit_field.G;
```

Comment: What if the structure is anonymous, In that case how can i access its members ?

Comment: @vikram The struct IS anonymous, it doesn't have a type name. What you want is a non-standard extension (which most compilers support). What compiler are you using and what platform. Also, I'm assuming this is in c?

Comment: Thnx @Cramer,Yes the code is in C, I am using Code composer studio v5.0. I have a piece of code where i have a structure inside union with no type name and  no instance and still we want to access the structure member using instance of union, i want to know is it possible, if yes how ?

Comment: @vikram Thought so, googling your error without quotes and without "G" - second result was this: http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/compiler/f/343/p/270895/946489.aspx